# Angular 7: como atualizar a variável no html automaticamente quando o valor da mesma for alterada no arquivo .ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, formulário

Eu tenho uma variável que recebe valor quando a página renderiza, e ele parece corretamente no template. Entanto se eu alterar o valor dela com a página já carregada o valor no .ts fica atualizando (conferido com console.log) mas no html permanece sem mudança.

Eu já tentei utiliar o ngModel mas isso não deu certo porque também estou utilizando um array de objetos e objetos desse array.

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itens">            
     <textarea class="textarea" id="item-textarea" [value]="item.text"> 
     </textarea>
</div>
```

Ts

```
public itens:any[] = [];

constructor() {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.initItens();
    this.changeItens();
}

initItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Hello world";
    this.itens.push(item);
}

changeItens() {
    let item = new Item();
    item.text = "Bye bye World";
    this.itens.push(item);
    console.log(this.itens); //saída conforme o esperado
}
```

Gostaria de saber o que é necessário ser feito para poder sempre que atualizar a variável no arquivo .ts também atualizar no html, para o angular 7.

Obrigada.

Comment: Tenta assim: this.itens=[...this.itens,item];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta mudar a referencia do seu array pro angular saber que algo mudou.

```
 this.itens=[...this.itens,item]
```

Comment: ajudou, obrigada